# services in different ports or same port but different endpoint names

Tags: node.js, web-services, go, graphql, microservices

i have small services use GraphQl Federation so far using Go, right now the endpoint each services are different Ports, and still in one codebase because still small codes but i am sure this project gonna be more Large, also the gateway in one code base as well because it is only few line with Apollo gateway to register the services
right now the services like this

```
"accounts": localhost:4001/graph,
"payments": localhost:4002/graph,
"inventories": localhost:4003/graph
```

is that good if i make the endpoint like this because i still in one codebase

```
"accounts": localhost:4001/graph/accounts,
"payments": localhost:4001/graph/payments,
"inventories": localhost:4001/graph/inventories
```

and i want to save money also to run the small services in one virtual machine :)

Comment: I think the two methods consume almost the same amount of system resources.I prefer multiple ports. Because it is convenient for load balancing.Just like microservices

Comment: is that good also to use that services in one machine ?? :D

Comment: two methods consume almost the same amount of system resources. Choose one you like